# FirestoreRecyclerView is not displaying data from Firestore DB after activity restart

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have this activity from my Online Voting Application that has a RecyclerView based on Firestore UI where it displays all of my data with the field, "registrationStatus" that has a value of "Pending". At the application start, the data is displayed but after going to a different activity by interacting with the items on the RecyclerView, then going back again to the previous activity, the data is not displayed but somehow when I touch the blank RecyclerView, I can still access the data that is previously displayed. I can't seem to know where and what code is causing this to happen. If you can lend me a hand on this problem, that would be lovely.

This is at the start of the application:

[image: Start of the Application]

This is the activity after interacting with the the items from the RecyclerView:
[image: RecyclerView Item Activity]

And now going back to the previous activity:

[image: Going back to the RecyclerView Activity]

This is the code that is related to the RecyclerView

```
public class AdminHomepage extends AppCompatActivity {

Button logOut;
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference notebookRef = db.collection("Candidates");
RecyclerView recyclerView;
AdminCandidateAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_homepage);

    //Buttons
    logOut = findViewById(R.id.adminLogOut);

    //Recycler View Things
    setUpRecyclerView();

    //Log-Out Button Tap
    logOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mAuth.signOut();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged Out Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

    //Click Listener for the RecyclerView
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AdminCandidateAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
            AdminCandidateItem note = documentSnapshot.toObject(AdminCandidateItem.class);

            String name = note.getCandidateFullName();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EvaluateCandidate.class).putExtra("name", name));
        }
    });
}

private void setUpRecyclerView() {

    Query query = notebookRef.whereEqualTo("registrationStatus", "Pending").orderBy("candidateFullName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<AdminCandidateItem> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<AdminCandidateItem>()
            .setQuery(query, AdminCandidateItem.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new AdminCandidateAdapter(options);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.candidateList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have resolved my problem. It appears that the RecyclerView cannot display the items because I have assigned the RecyclerView to wrap all of its contents. By assigning a custom height size, the items are now being displayed even after the activity restart.

This is the XML code for that part before the height change:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/candidateList"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />
```

And this is the code after the height change:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/candidateList"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />
```

So I have set a custom layout_height of 300dp to make space for the items for my RecyclerView

This is now the activity after the change:

[image]